# Why does VBScript run from %userprofile%\Documents when run from Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

**Short Background**

I've got an application that I built in Excel, and I'm attempting to add functionality where Excel acts as a controller and runs different VBScript files (I know this sounds like an odd case, but bear with me). To test the concept, I wrote a short VBScript that simply `Echo`s the path to the folder that the script is in.

**VBScript (`run-from-excel.vbs`)**

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

scriptPath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
WScript.Echo(scriptPath)
```

When run with `cscript run-from-excel.vbs` from a console in the proper directory, the output is: `C:\Users\cmfonvi\dev\vbscript`, which is as expected.

Now, for the Excel integration. I wrote a simple `Sub` that runs a VBScript file through `WScript` on the console.

**VBA - Excel**

```
Sub runVBScript(filePath As String)
    Shell "wscript " & filePath, vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

I now run this `Sub`, with the command

```
runVBScript (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\run-from-excel.vbs")
```

(the workbook and VBScript are currently in the same directory, so this works). However, the output is not as I expected. The window it opens outputs `C:\Users\cmfonvi\Documents`, which means that somehow the `wscript` process running the VBScript is initialized in the `%userprofile%\Documents` directory.

My question is two-fold:

1. Why is this the case?
2. How can I make the console initialize in the proper directory (say, for example, in `%userprofile%\Desktop`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` (in your VBScript code) is the current working directory. `ActiveWorkbook.Path` (in your VBA code) is the path of the directory containing the active workbook. Those two paths are not necessarily the same. If you want the VBScript code to output the directory where the script is located you need to use something like this:

```
fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
```

If you want the VBScript to use a particular working directory change it like this:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.CurrentDirectory = "C:\some\folder"
```

Comment: The change to the VBScript worked! Thanks much. Before I mark as accepted, I'd like a little more clarification about why it chose the Documents folder, since neither of my files resided there (they are both in the same directory)

Comment: The Documents folder is the default working directory for Office applications. Try for instance [`debug.print CurDir`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251649.aspx) in the direct window of the VBA editor.

Comment: Thanks! Never realized there was a difference between that and ActiveWorkbook.Path, which I usually utilize